# Split returned string into muliple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string containing a hierarchy of items separated by a '/' character.

E.g.  Class\Order\Family\Genus\Species

I need to split out this string such that each value is its own column as well as displaying the original full string

E.g.

```
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\Panthera tigris  
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\Panthera leo  
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\Panthera pardus
```

becomes

```
Classification Class Order Family  Genus Species  
-------------- ----- ----- ------  ----- -------
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\tigris Mammalia  Carnivora Felidae Pathera tigris  
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\leo Mammalia  Carnivora Felidae Pathera leo  
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\pardus  Mammalia  Carnivora Felidae Pathera pardus
```

Finally, not all string will have 5 values so the script will need to
enter NULL for values that don't exist

E.g.

```
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae
```

becomes

```
Classification Class Order Family  Genus Species  
Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae Mammalia  Carnivora Felidae NULL NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

It uses common table expressions to split the string into parts (levels). Please not that I need to add `\` to split it correctly so the input string shouldn't have `\` at the end.

Then you just get the value for each level.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(500) = 'Mammalia\Carnivora\Felidae\Panthera\Panthera tigris'

;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@string + '\', 1, CHARINDEX('\', @string, 1) - 1) AS Part, 
        SUBSTRING(@string + '\', CHARINDEX('\', @string, 1) + 1, LEN(@string + '\') - CHARINDEX('\', @string, 1) + 1) AS Remainder,
        0 AS Level

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUBSTRING(cte.Remainder, 1, CHARINDEX('\', cte.Remainder, 1) - 1) AS Part, 
        SUBSTRING(cte.Remainder, CHARINDEX('\', cte.Remainder, 1) + 1, LEN(cte.Remainder) - CHARINDEX('\', cte.Remainder, 1) + 1) AS Remainder,
        cte.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM cte
    WHERE CHARINDEX('\', cte.Remainder, 1) > 0
)

SELECT
    @string Classification,
    (SELECT Part FROM cte WHERE Level = 0) Class,
    (SELECT Part FROM cte WHERE Level = 1) [Order],
    (SELECT Part FROM cte WHERE Level = 2) Family,
    (SELECT Part FROM cte WHERE Level = 3) Genus,
    (SELECT Part FROM cte WHERE Level = 4) Species
```